# On framework upgrade to .Net 6, Selenium UI tests are not running

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nunit, .net-6.0, uitest

[1st part of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Lkc.png)

[2nd part of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Jws.png)

[packaged installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TkqQ.png)

We recently upgraded to use a newer version of the .NET Framework  and getting the error shown in images.

```
NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 1 of 1 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Non-Explicit run
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : Stack overflow.
```